# How to add a component using directive in angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to add a code completion in an input (or textarea) element. Similar to what you will see in modern IDE.

I already have a directive that look for some keyboard shortcut to add some variable delimiter in my input element:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[askGenerateVariable]'
})
export class GenerateVariableDirective {

  constructor(private element: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(e: KeyboardEvent) {

    if (e.ctrlKey && (e.key === '1' || e.key === '2' || e.key === '3' || e.key === '4')) {
      ...
    }
  }

}
```

But now I want this to add another component (a component that display a list of item in a box).

Is there a way to do that?
I have try making it a component and add a template, but the content of the template doesn't show anywhere. Probably because an input do not have a end tag.

I have the reference to the element. I know that I can add stuff to it, but how to add another component?

Thanks

Comment: See [Angular 6 Upgrade - Breaking Changes & Features - What's New?](https://youtu.be/Xr5l7lT--YU) at about 12:15, Maximilian Schwarzmuller talks about using Angular Elements where the component is provided within dynamically entered HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @Roman answer pointed me to the easy way to resolve my problem:

I need two part:

1. A component with a template to display my list of items for the auto-complete
2. A directive that will be used on the input (or texarea) to "trigger" the display of the auto-complete

The component is added only once on the page. Anywhere.
The directive is use on all the input fields where I want to have the auto-complete.

The trick here is to give a reference of the component to the directive. The directive can then call methods or change properties on the component.

```
<ask-code-autocomplete #AskAutoComplete></ask-code-autocomplete>
<input [askVariableAutoComplete]="AskAutoComplete">
```

In the directive, you need to add an input:

```
@Input('askVariableAutoComplete') codeAutocompleteComponent: AsCodeAutocompleteComponent;
```

Now in the directive you can use it to do thing like:

```
this.codeAutocompleteComponent.show(newTop, newLeft);
```

Answer (score 0):

The default approach would be to wrap the input into a component. Thus you can simply modify DOM and control anything whats going on with the input.

Keeping it your way you can try to use power of css(see https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp and https://css-tricks.com/css-attr-function-got-nothin-custom-properties/ for details). However this approach is very limited, so I wouln't even try.

I would not recommend any DOM manipulations from directive cause it is not what it was designed for.

To see how to wrap input to a component that has functionality of autocomplete you can check how material team did it here https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/lib/autocomplete